# Defining Macros that are equal to functions that return objects in C++

Tags: c++, static, macros, singleton

So I have the singleton pattern working the way I want to, I think the main problem is something with pointers and refrences. ("..." represents irrelevent code).

Universe.h

```
...    
#define TheUniverse Universe::GetInstance ();
...
public:
static Universe& GetInstance ();
...
private:
static Universe* x_instance;
...
```

Universe.cpp

```
...
Universe* Universe::x_instance = NULL;
...
    Universe& Universe::GetInstance ()
{
    if ( x_instance == NULL )
    {
        x_instance = new Universe ();
    }
    return *x_instance;
}
...
```

Main.cpp

```
...
//This Works
Universe& universe = TheUniverse;

universe.Initialize();

//This also Works
Universe::GetInstance().Initialize();
//This Does Not (and I do not know why)
TheUniverse.Initialize();
//CMake says "error: expected primary-expression before '.' token TheUniverse.Initizlize();"
```

So, why do I have to set TheUniverse macro to a variable before I can use it? And is there a way for me to bypass this and not have to use a variable?

Comment: "error: expected primary-expression before '.' token TheUniverse. **Initizlize()**" - is this a typo?

Comment: Also, there is a semicolon in macro that should not be there.

Comment: Well regarding the my singleton pattern, I got it from refrencing https://github.com/angel2d/angel2d/blob/master/Code/Angel/Infrastructure/World.h and https://github.com/angel2d/angel2d/blob/master/Code/Angel/Infrastructure/World.cpp . Im rather new to C++ (comming from java) and I'll admit there are some things I just don't know well at all. But I need to know if you saying that project was not done well, because I look into this source code alot for when I want to learn something new.

Comment: I think that atcually solved the problem @n0rd good catch. It was the semicolon not the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you defined `TheUniverse` as `Universe::GetInstance();`, with a semicolon. Therefore, after macros are processed, you get `Universe::GetInstance();.Initialize();` which is obviously not what you want. To fix the problem simply remove the semicolon in the macro definition.

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem. Also shout-out to @n0rd for the same answer in the comments.

Comment: @ThomasSteinholz no problem. Remember, macros don't work like constants; they represent code, not values.